# Syncing a Vagrant box across computers (Mac/Windows)

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, vagrant

I will be working on a Vagrant box across multiple computers, both Mac (10.8.5) and Windows (7/8). How can I sync the files so that I can always work on an up-to-date version of the box? I'm comfortable using symlinks with Dropbox.

I tried syncing my VirtualBox folder across systems with the aforementioned Dropbox symlinks, but each has OS-specific information in the folder. The same is true with the Vagrant folders. What specifically do I need to sync to have a copy on each computer? How would I go about setting up each computer?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question.  Have you tried this?  what issues did you encounter?

Comment: That's a very good point. I've updated the post. Thank you!